# Click on MarkUp points Forge

Tags: javascript, autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk, autodesk-model-derivative

Hi I'm trying to use this Forge markup Sample:

```
 https://github.com/wallabyway/markupExt
```

i found this line in markupExt.js but nothing happen:

```
    this.raycaster.params.PointCloud.threshold = 5; 
// hit-test markup size.  Change this if markup 'hover' doesn't work
```

[image]
but when i run the script i can't click on the points for showing cards

this is my console return:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The parameter `this.raycaster.params.PointCloud.threshold = 5` sets the hit-test radius to 5 units.

The problem with that sample is that it is geared towards the world-scale of a fusion360 model, and not a Revit model.

Try the markupExt.js example taken from this Revit example: https://github.com/apprentice3d/ForgeViewerExtensions

This will help with setting up the mouseX and Y coordinates into the correct scale for the hit-test.

Sorry about that.
Let me know if that helps
Cheers
Michael

Comment: hi thank you i'll check :) sorry for the late answer.